# Slow shared NAS storage for VM cluster

Tags: storage, network-attached-storage, shared-hosting, slow-connection

I have a problem with a very slow virtual machines.
I have two HP DL380 G6 servers in the cluster that are connected to the Synology NAS 2416+. Everything is connected via the HP 1620 Switch.
On the server I configured 3x 1Gbps NIC teaming with LACP. The same configuration and on the NAS device and the switch.
NAS box has 4 x 2TB WD Red drive in RAID 10 field and 60GB SSD as a read cache.
I set the iSCSI targets and set up all the instructions from the Internet.
At these targets have included multipath.
Hosts and VM are Server 2012 r2.
Now my question is whether this is a good setup or anything else to do in order to speed up performance.
The current read and write speeds are 120/120 MB around and it was really ok but when I set 4 VM as RDP farm and on the one install SQL 2014 thing is quite slow.
From performance monitor i get only 1Gbps speed.
Please for recommendations and thank you to everyone for your answers.
Greeting

Comment: Are you CERTAIN that all three of the host-to-switch LACP links *AND* all three of the storage-to-switch LACP links are handling equal traffic? This can be a VERY complex setup and often doesn't work at all.

Comment: LACP with iSCSI is a no-no, if you want to use mutiple NICs for iSCSI traffic you should treat them as dfferent networks and use multipath. Also, iSCSI traffic should have its own, dedicated network adapter(s); it shouldn't be mixed with host or VM traffic. Oh, and don't forget to enable jumbo frames, or you'll waste a lot of bandwidth.

Comment: Thanks for answers.The switch,server and storage reports that all bonding is ok. I have tryed connecting all three adapters to different vlan dedicated only to server to storage connectivity  but that isnt making any different to speed.The jumbo frames are set to 9000

Answer (score 3):

> On the server I configured 3x 1Gbps NIC teaming with LACP. The same configuration and on the NAS device and the switch. NAS box has 4 x 2TB WD Red drive in RAID 10 field and 60GB SSD as a read cache. I set the iSCSI targets and set up all the instructions from the Internet.

iSCSI and LACP don't mix well.

https://slog.starwindsoftware.com/lacp-vs-mpio-on-windows-platform/

http://www.altaro.com/hyper-v/teaming-and-mpio-for-storage-in-hyper-v-2012/

Devastate LACP setup and build subnets and configure MPIO. Round Robin of course. Synology isn't fastest target you could get but you should saturate 3x Ethernet with any virtual LUN pinpointed to SSDs.

Comment: Thank you all for reply.the setup now work with subnets and mpio.succesfully run 12 vm.the speed isnt the best but it works